# Switch to a differnet UIViewController when the device orientation changes

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, uiwindow

I am currently building an app for iPad where the view structure is completely different depending on the device orientation.

When the app is in portrait I am using the ECSlidingViewController library to support left and right sliding menu's (like facebook or path).

When the app is in landscape I need to display a splitviewcontroller so that the left hand menu is always visible.

Does anybody know of the best solution to this problem?

I have tried changing the RootViewController of the UIWindow when an orientation change is detected but this gave some very strange results....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Some better than other, but mostly it will depends on the needs of your specific situation.

1. Replace the `rootViewController` as you mentioned during rotation.
2. Always use a `UISplitViewController` and use a `segue` to with `replace` to replace the `detailViewController` when rotating between portrait and landscape.
3. Use/make a custom container view controller which adds/removes the appropriate view controller on rotation using `addChildViewController:` and `removeFromParentViewController:`

Extremely crude example of choice 3.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self.childViewControllers[0].view removeFromSuperView];
    [self.childViewControllers[0] removeFromParentViewController];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        [self addChildViewController:portraitVC];
        [self.view addSubview:portraitVC.view];
    } else {
        [self addChildViewController:landscapeVC];
        [self.view addSubview:landscapeVC.view];
    }
}
```

From what you've said, I'd guess option 3 would be the best fit. All this said though, I'm not entirely convinced you need to be switching view controllers, but I'm not familiar with `ECSlidingViewController` and what it offers so I'm can't be certain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to reset the rootViewController when rotation is detected. Do you know how I can do this? When I have tried it it seems to do some strange layering and rotation....

Comment: The problem  is that the main viewcontroller of my ECSlidingViewController implementation needs to extend a particular subclass which will conflict when using UISplitViewController.

Comment: I ended up changing my implementation to the solution 3 suggested above, which fixed the problem.

Comment: I really don't think setting your `rootViewController` is your best choice. Using a custom container view controller will give you a lot more options and functionality while still giving you the same behavior you desire. It does not matter what your view controllers sub-class, the effect should still work fine.